# As a color name, would "chili" or "chile" be the same as "chilli"?

Tags: word-choice, differences

The [South African flag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_South_Africa) Wikipedia article consistently refers to the reddish color in the SA flag as *chilli*,
both outside of and within quotes from SA's official interim heraldic description and the SA Constitution's plain-English flag description.  (However, [Heraldry#Tinctures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heraldry#Tinctures) does not list *chilli* among the common heraldry colors.)

I looked (not successfully) for references for *chilli* as a color, and am inclined to think the color would be the same whether called *chilli, chili* or *chile*.  Does anyone know different, or have access to an authoritative reference?

[meta.cooking.SE](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/619/chilli-chili-or-chile) considers the "Chilli, Chili or Chile?" debacle at great length, but implicitly treating chilies as foodstuffs, not colors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [NGram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=chili+red%2Cchilli+red%2Cchile+red&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), *chili red* is by far the most common of the three:

http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/chart?content=chili%20red%2Cchilli%20red%2Cchile%20red&corpus=0&smoothing=3&year_start=1900&year_end=2000

*Chili red* also seems to be common online--one [site](http://www.annesage.com/blog/2010/06/color-lust-chili-pepper.html) refers to it as a color that's currently in fashion. *Chilli red* also turns up pictures of the color, but it seems less common. *Chile red* mostly turns up the picture of the pepper itself.

By common usage, I think you could use "chili" or "chilli". Historically, "chili red" has been the most popular, and I think it might be most widely understood.

Answer (score 1):

"Chilli" and "chili" are different spellings of the same thing, it seems, according to the New Oxford American Dictionary:

[image]

"Chil(l)i red", the color, as far as I can tell, comes from the plant name, so the same should apply (i.e., "chill red" and "chili red" are equivalent).

Comment: What is about _chili_ used to mean the color?

Comment: "Chili (red)" the color, I believe, is based on the name of the plant, so the same should apply.

Answer (score 1):

A little Googling (on [color "chilli red"] and [color "chili red"]) quickly turns up numerous instances of both *chilli red* and *chili red* as color descriptors. Some are associated with pictures; the pictures for the two spellings show similar ranges of reds. I see no reason to doubt that *chilli red* and *chili red* are simply UK and US spellings of the same color term, just as *chilli* and *chili* are the UK and US spellings of the plant name. (And no, *chil(l)i red* is definitely not a standard heraldic tincture!)